# Как парсить дату?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Какой паттерн распарсит дату в таком формате `Fri Oct 05 23:57:19 GMT+00:00 2018`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю, можно вот так, просто поменяйте местами как вам будет удобно:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a DateFormat and set the timezone to GMT.
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    try {
        // Convert string into Date
        Date today = df.parse("Mon, 16 Apr 2018 00:00:00 GMT+08:00");
        System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Результат будет:

```
Today = Sun, 15 Apr 2018 16:00:00 GMT
```